# internationalization in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am developing an app in English. I want to change this app into French.

For static data I am able to do this. But For dynamic data I am unable to do this. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: What kind of dynamic data are you dealing with?

Comment: @Claus Broch - Maybe something like @"You are logged in as user: %@";

Answer (score 0):

You can write this "StringKey" = "You are logged in at: %@" in your localizedstrings file and in your code you do something like this
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"StringKey", @""), server];

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at NSLocalizedString or NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue.

```
NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"KEY_FOR_STRING", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], @"VISIBLE_DESCRIPTION", @"DEVELOPER_DESCRIPTION")
```

From above, your VISIBLE_DESCRIPTION could include %@'s, %i, etc for dynamic replacement.